# How to fix numpy fail with missing libcblas.so.3 on alpine docker

Tags: docker, numpy, alpine-linux

I had installed numpy on alpine docker and everything looked good before running numpy:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: Error loading shared library libcblas.so.3: No such file or directory (needed by /app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

I found that licblas.so might be in /usr/lib/ as mentioned here: [alpine blas](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=edge&name=blas&arch=x86&repo=community)

but it wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

After installing lapack, the missing file libcblas.so.3 appeared in /usr/lib/:

```
apk add lapack
```

I had openblas-dev installed from before but that was not sufficient.